# Was there a melee weapon that was used by many people at the same time?

Tags: weapons

Yes. That's the question. Does anyone know about any melee weapons that were used by more than one person at the same time? That is, two or more people fighting using one weapon together.

Comment: Would a 2 or 3 rider chariot count?

Comment: Is this about items that were purpose-made as multi-user weapons and rather than improvised weaponry (such as a length of chain held by a different person at each end)?

Comment: I could see multiple people on a pike repelling a charge.

Comment: I foremost mean weapon designed to be wielded by more than one person.

Comment: Every cavalry  weapon.  Seriously,  question is a hypothetical,  and will generate lots of argument about definitions,  but very little information. Also fails basic plausibility;  tandem wield would require insane amounts of training, and would not be resilient in a dynamic battlefield.   Formations are as close as you'll get.

Comment: Arguably,  a shield wall is an example.  Or a infantry square.  Or a cav charge.

Comment: Not technically a melee weapon but you might find the [punt gun](http://rarehistoricalphotos.com/punt-gun-1910-1920/) interesting.

Comment: I read a paper the Grimm about an accident about such a weapon: Seven men from Swabia operated a large pike in concert, however they all drowned. The practice was discontinued.

Answer (score 6):

In its early form, at least, a [battering ram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battering_ram) was a log manned by several people, that was hurled against the doors of enemy fortifications to break them down. After which there would be hand to hand fighting.

Also, chariots, like modern tanks, typically had several men. One or more drivers, plus soldiers to wield the actual weapons such as spears or swords.

Comment: Battering ram is not a melee weapon.

Comment: I would consider the original battering ram a melee weapon because there were typically enemy soldiers behind the door, and the whole purpose of using a battering ram was to get "up close and personal." Certainly a "log" could be used as a melee weapon like a club. This is in contrast to cannon, catapults, and "later" battering rams that were more sophisticated siege engines than logs.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I know already about the early version of battering ram and about pikes. Chariots don't really fit my inner definition of a meele weapon... You could add ships and boats to that too... It seems that pikes fits the best. I was hoping for something that I wouldn't hear about already though. It would be interesting if someone used "a giant hammer" to crush enemies from afar.